# Tensorflow: unable to navigate to tensorflow folder using docker [Windows 10 Home edition]

Tags: docker, windows-10, tensorflow

My intention is to experiment with transfer learning, so I am following this post: https://petewarden.com/2016/02/28/tensorflow-for-poets/

I came up to this step: `docker run -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:0.7.1-devel` but mine is modified as I would like to persist the data:
`docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 --name tf -v /$(pwd)/TensorFlow-docker:/notebooks  b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow`

and then the post says that the step has been completed, you’ll find yourself in a new terminal. This is where I am stuck.
Where is this new terminal `root@xxxx`? It cannot be the docker terminal since it is running the ipython server and when I checked my linux VM .. it was more like `root@default`. 
I then try to go into the container via this command in a new docker terminal: `docker exec -it tf /bin/bash` and I get: `root@<container_id>:/notebooks#` When I type `ls` it comes empty! How can i access the folders in the container? More specifically `tensorflow` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below command will download docker image of `tensorflow` with tag `0.7.1-devel`

```
docker run -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:0.7.1-devel
```

Once downloading complete you will be in `tensorflow` docker container.
it will look like :

```
root@e738ecb0e80a:/#
```

there you can see directory using command:

```
ls /tensorflow
```

once you exit . your docker will stop. 
if you want your docker run continuously even you exit from docker then use `-d` option.  like:

```
 docker run -d -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:0.7.1-devel
```

if you want your data persist of directory `/tensorflow`

```
docker run -d -it -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 --name tf -v /$(pwd)/TensorFlow-docker:/tensorflow  b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

after that login to docker container using command:

```
docker exec -it tf /bin/bash
```

you will get docker shell like:

```
root@e738ecb0e80a:/#
```

> you’ll find yourself in a new terminal. This is where I am stuck.
>   Where is this new terminal root@xxxx?

link that you given in your question is saying about `tensorflow` docker container shell.